What to pursue Masters in
I will graduate with a BTech in Comp Sci and Engineering, and a BSc in Data Science and Applications. I do not yet know my goal career, but I would like it to be related to machine learning, AI or data science. I'm very math oriented. Would a masters in math and then a Phd in a specialization like machine learning work? I think it would give me more options in what to specialize in. Or should I pursue a masters in say data science? Any advice would be helpful

Interesting advice posted here
